# How to pass specific parts of Hash from url to iframe source url?

Tags: javascript, iframe, hash

The URL of the current page contains a hash: test123.com/go/#1/140/-220

I would like to only grab specific parts of the hash: 140 and -220 from the url and append those to specific parts of an iframe source.

iframe source= test123.com/goiframe&value1=140&value2=-220

Where value1= the 140 from the url and value2= the -220 from the URL.

Is this possible with location.hash?

Comment: Yes. `location.hash` gives you the has string. You then need to parse it. Have you tried doing that? Take a look at String [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) which is what you likely want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, the response is just a string so parse it and construct your new url. Below I split the hash on a / and remove the first element as that is the base hash. Then just construct the url.

Note: I am using literals here. If you don't want to you could manually construct the strings.

Eg:

```js
// Manually update hash for test. 
window.location.hash = '#1/140/-220';
console.log('Original Hash: ' , window.location.hash);

// Get those entries but remove the inital has part. 
let entries = window.location.hash.split('/').slice(1);
console.log('Entries parsed: ', entries);

// Create the new url now. 
let newURL = 'test123.com/goiframe';


for(let i = 0; i < entries.length; i++){
    newURL += `&value${i + 1}=${entries[i]}`;
}

console.log('New URL: ', newURL);
```

EDIT: 
Basically I just got rid of the loop and said lat and lng. Update as needed.

```js
// Manually update hash for test. 
window.location.hash = '#1/140/-220';
console.log('Original Hash: ' , window.location.hash);

// Get those entries but remove the inital has part. 
let entries = window.location.hash.split('/').slice(1);
console.log('Entries parsed: ', entries);

// Create the new url now. 
let newURL = `test123.com/goiframe&lat=${entries[0]}&lng=${entries[1]}`;

console.log('New URL: ', newURL);
```

Comment: I should have been more specific the value1 and value2 are actually lat and long so it would look like: test123.com/goiframe&lat=140&long=-220 .... There's also some values after those values in the iframe source: test123.com/goiframe&lat=140&long=-220&moreinfohere  Does that change your snippet?

Comment: @Chris That makes it a little different. Will you only ever have those two? Could always just set  it that way. See edit for a straightforward way here.

Comment: Thanks. The lat and long variables won’t always be the same in the url.

Comment: Then please edit your question with more  details. We can't guess what you want.